# How to get a variable's value in TSQL from C# code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, change-tracking

I have the following code to be executed and I want to get the value of @synchronization_version from c#. Does any one know how this could be handled?

```
DECLARE @synchronization_version BIGINT
SET @synchronization_version = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION();
```

Comment: Use a scalar function?

Comment: thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way is to use SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar. See this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx .

Your SQL query would look like this:

```
SELECT Convert(BigInt,CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION());
```

I modified the MSDN code as follows. This should work:

```
public static Int64 GetSynchronizationVersion(string connString)
{
    Int64 synchronizationVersion = 0;
    string sql =
        "SELECT Convert(BigInt,CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION());";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        //This query has no parameters.
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            synchronizationVersion = (Int64)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    return synchronizationVersion;
}
```

This operation is called ExecuteScalar because it returns a single value (a scalar) rather than a set of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a procedure like

```
create procedure Sp_getdata
as
begin
DECLARE @synchronization_version BIGINT OUTPUT
SET @synchronization_version = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION();
SELECT @synchronization_version;
end
```

Call the procedure from C#

```
SqlParameter outData = new SqlParameter("@synchronization_version", SqlDbType.BIGINT){ Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Then just read the value of output parameter

```
long result = outData.Value;
```